# MySQL - how to export CSV with NULL values as empty?

Tags: mysql

Right now i use MySQLWorkbench to export a CSV file but if the field as a NULL values it's getting exported as:

`value1, /N, value2, /N, /N`

How can i make sure it's exported as:
`value1, , value2, ,`

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `coalesce(FieldName,'')` to return empty string instead of `Null`

Comment: What if field is not string?

Comment: @a.oberon instead of empty string you return the default value for that data type.

Comment: But default value for Integer can not be empty as needed =)